# c++ removing whitespace fails by using iterators

Tags: c++, string, iterator

This codes compiles and works as intended but the comment line doesnt for some reason can anybody tell me why.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter a line:\n";
    std::string Line;
    std::getline(std::cin,Line);
    const std::string Whitespace = " \t\t\f\v\n\r";
    //std::string Line= std::string(Line.find_first_not_of(Whitespace),Line.find_last_not_of(Whitespace)+1); // Why doesnt this work?
    std::string Line= Line.substr(Line.find_first_not_of(Whitespace),Line.find_last_not_of(Whitespace)+1);
    std::cout << "You entered:" << Line << "\n";
}
```

Edit I was under the impression find las returns a iterator not a size_t so that is why I was confused

Comment: what does find_first_not_of() return? looks like indexes and not iterators.

Comment: "doesnt work for some reason".  How does it not work?  You are asking people to guess your input and output.

Comment: Nothing works! Note the length in `string substr (size_t pos = 0, size_t len = npos) const;`

Comment: Okay, so we know you don't get errors. Could you share some input/output that doesn't work the way you think it should?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only the commented line, but another will also fail if there is space in the begin of string.

First line fail (to compile) because `string::find_first_not_of` return `size_t`. And construct `string` from two size just make no sense.

Second line may fail because `string::substr` accept length (not end) as it's second parameter.

Comment: Oh, and you don't include <string> (or you include it in compiler settings?)